# About finding chars in text with AS3

Tags: regex, actionscript-3, search

I have to validate a textfield in AS3 if there are chars like # $ % @ ~ | {} [] / \ etc. i.e find unnecessary chars and remove them from the textfield.

I use a search AS3 function which works with regular expressions, but I am not good at RegEx so can anyone help me with this? I would like a regular expression so that a search function searches the characters above and if it finds any of them then returns true.

Comment: This tool might be of some help: http://gskinner.com/RegExr/

Comment: very useful, awesome flex tool, thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following snippet removes the blacklisted characters you have defined (not recommended):

### Option 1: Character class with blacklist.

```js
text = text.replace(/[#$%@~|{}[\]/\\]+/g, '');
```

But there are a *LOT* of other control, punctuation and Unicode characters that you probably also want to avoid (e.g. `[¥®^«±µ¼½¾]` etc.. Instead, it is most likely better to define which chars you wish to allow, and then remove all characters that are *NOT* the ones to be allowed.

### Option 2: Negated character class with whitelist.

Lets say you want to allow all latin letters, numbers, spaces, dots, dashes, underscores and colons (i.e. `[A-Za-z0-9 .\-_:]`). Here is a snippet that will remove all character that are not in the whitelist:

```js
text = text.replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9 .\-_:]+/g, '');
```

Comment: surely whitelisted char list is better solution, thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 1):

There may be a more concise regex, but for the characters you've given, try this.

```
var pattern:RegExp = /[#$%@~\|{}\[\]\\\/]/
```